# Django - How to get the length of the array through GET request?

Tags: django, http

I have a http get request that has an array, particularly:

```
[29/Sep/2014 16:04:47] "GET /webapp/ajax_retreiveServerSideUsernames/?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5
Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&
columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&searc
h%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&csrfmiddlewaretoken=Something&_=1412028280135 HTTP/1.1" 200
 1436
```

My question is that how do I get the "length" of a particular array in a GET request?

For example the array order:`order[i][column]`.

However, there may be cases with unkown array size.

If I know that i = 0, then I can use `request.get['order[0][column]']` to get the content of the first array's column data.

I tried to use `request.GET.getlist('order[column]')` or `request.GET.getlist('order')` with no avail.

Comment: What about `request.GET.getlist('order[]')`?

Comment: Do you have any control over the format of the GET request? That's a Rails/PHP style structure, and not how it would usually be done with Django.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the jQuery Plugin uses a PHP style structure. It seems to me that %5B stands for [, and %5D stands for ].

Comment: @alecxe request.GET.getlist('order[]') does not work, it only returns an empty list